# MySQL "not in" Query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to achieve something like this `SELECT * FROM myindex where _id not in (1, 2, 3)` in Elasticsearch. One way to do this is:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 200,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "_id": {
                                            "query": 1,
                                            "type": "phrase"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "_id": {
                                            "query": 2,
                                            "type": "phrase"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "_id": {
                                            "query": 3,
                                            "type": "phrase"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this approach wouldn't scale for a big array because this will be a huge query. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: hi @amit-tripathi, what is exactly '_id'? the Elasticsearch uid that identifies the document or a field indexed in all documents?

Comment: @xecgr `_id` is a unique id for each document, its not indexed. `uid` is calculated using `_id` and `type`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
GET _search
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not" : {
        "terms" : {
          "_id" : [1,2,3]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to write an inner query to populate that array `[1,2,3]` ?

Comment: @barat: what if I have thousand of ids and i want to filter it out. How can I achieve this. pls suggest I have encountered the same problem

Comment: ES doesn't have subquersies like SQL. From other hand you may try this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html 
First query to grab IDs, and 2nd to make a query.
From other hand - probably you're doing something wrong. Can't you just have separate index for it? In ES only Source is taking lot of space, and you can have this data indexed in multiple ways.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this very simply with:

```
query: {
        bool: {
          must_not: {
            terms: {
              _id: array
            }
          }
        }
      }
```